# Can't save cookies on my page, but works in Netbeans

Tags: php, cookies, netbeans

I have used the same code for almost a year and now  it stopped working.
I only added one more variable to the string and chrome refuses to accept the cookie on my page, but the same code on Netbeans works.

```
$cookie_name = "Hoppvader";
$cookie_value = $Vindstyrka .",". $Avstand .",". $Staende . "," . $Markera . "," . $Hojd . "," . $Oversatt . "," . $Vaderbilder . "," . $Translate . "," . $Lufttryck . "," . $color . "," . $LHP_oversatt . "," . $VindBilder;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30 * 12 * 10), "/"); // 10 years
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $cookie_value . '"); </script>';
```

A typical value of the cookie may look like: `1, m/s,1, m,N,Y,m,Y,Y,Y,Y,#FFFFC1,Y,1`
And the new value in the string is ",1" or `$VindBilder`.
The javascript alert prompts the value correct.

I have also tried to roll back the code to where it was before and it still wont save the cookie on my browser.
I also tried it in IE and it saves the cookie, but without the last value ",1".

Anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: Better use `print_r($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]); exit;` to see the content of the cookie

Comment: I can't use that, because the cookie is never created. The code is wrong or the browsers block it all of the sudden by some reason

Comment: check in headers sent to browser if there is a `Set-Cookie` header. If there is not, problem comes from PHP, if there is one, it's from browser. By the way try some easier value, too debug a bit more, like `setcookie('test', 'testvalue', time() + 600);`

Comment: Mhhh, depends on which browser you use, under firefox its right click, inspect element, network, reload page, then set filter to HTML (bottom left, on the right of 'all'), then click on the request, and check in Response headers

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the window [link to screenshot](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/582788Capture.png)

Comment: I think I just realized my error. I have not checked the header and are not at the computer right now, it's lunch. But you have to set the cookie before any other operations, correct? I think I added something else to the code before the setcookie.

Comment: @Bob0t, thanks for the screenshot! will look in to it soon!

Comment: Yup! I had some other operations in between that keept the cookie from being created. It was a string that got set that created the problem. I thought it was only echos that created issues. Anyways thank you for your help Bob0t! feel free to type it out as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just answer your own question :) You found the solution, you write the answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason to be that setcookie  does not work if do any output prior to  setcookie.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

The problem was not setcookie, it was my mistake to have output before setcookie.